# Can you increase the magnetism of a material by increasing the heat?

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

> EPFL scientists have provided the first evidence ever that it is
> possible to generate a magnetic field by using heat instead of
> electricity.

https://actu.epfl.ch/news/using-heat-to-make-magnets/

Can you increase the magnetism of a material by increasing the heat of the material? If not, what are some ways to increase magnetism and can any of the methods generate a lot of heat as a result?

Comment: See ‘Curie temperature’ …

Answer (score 0):

Typically the magnetism of a ferromagnetic material will decrease as the temperature increases. This is because of a conflict between the microscopic moments wanting to align, and thermal fluctuations trying to misalign them.

At and above a material specific Curie temperature $T_C$ the thermal fluctuations win and the material becomes paramagnetic. If no external $B$ field is applied, all the microscopic moments are pointing in random directions, cancelling each other out such that the net macroscopic moment is zero.

To summarize: Magnetic susceptibility (the ratio between induced magnetization and inducing field) usually decreases with increasing temperature.

However there are some materials where this magnetic susceptibility increases with increasing temperature. They are discussed further here
[Why ceramic magnets have a positive temperature coefficient of their magnetization?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/690175/319201)